# Removing white background from GeoTIFF in Geoserver

Tags: raster, geoserver, gdal, geotiff-tiff, sld

I'm having trouble with removing white background/bounding box from raster in Geoserver. When I add WMS service in ArcMap or Autocad I'm seeing this white bounding box and to be fair I don't know how to remove it.

Here is example:

[image]

I even tried changing SLD styles in Geoserver but without any luck. Here is my .xml style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<sld:StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:sld="http://www.opengis.net/sld">
    <sld:UserLayer>
        <sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
            <sld:FeatureTypeConstraint/>
        </sld:LayerFeatureConstraints>
        <sld:UserStyle>
            <sld:Name>te</sld:Name>
            <sld:Title/>
            <sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
                <sld:Name/>
                <sld:Rule>
                    <sld:RasterSymbolizer>
                        <sld:Geometry>
                            <ogc:PropertyName>grid</ogc:PropertyName>
                        </sld:Geometry>
                        <sld:Opacity>1</sld:Opacity>
                        <sld:ChannelSelection>
                            <sld:RedChannel>
                                <sld:SourceChannelName>1</sld:SourceChannelName>
                            </sld:RedChannel>
                            <sld:GreenChannel>
                                <sld:SourceChannelName>2</sld:SourceChannelName>
                            </sld:GreenChannel>
                            <sld:BlueChannel>
                                <sld:SourceChannelName>3</sld:SourceChannelName>
                            </sld:BlueChannel>
                        </sld:ChannelSelection>
                    </sld:RasterSymbolizer>
                </sld:Rule>
            </sld:FeatureTypeStyle>
        </sld:UserStyle>
    </sld:UserLayer>
</sld:StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Image is in TIFF format with 3 bands. Is it problem in style format, image itself or Geoserver? 
Or is it even possible to host raster images without white bounding box as seen in picture above?
Any advice? :)

Comment: Do you have to use TIFF as output format? Could you try to use PNG and report the results?

Comment: Yes, I did..nothing happens..

Comment: I did come across this in the Geoserver manual http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld/extensions/composite-blend/example.html

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not it, thank you for effort :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I've finally figure it out. I had to install GDAL and used following command to remove white border (bounding box)
GDAL command:

```
D:\FOLDER_NAME\RASTERS>gdalwarp -dstalpha -srcnodata 256 -dstnodata 0 input.tif output.tif
```

`input.tif` is the name of the raster (eg. county_roads.tif)and `output.tif` is name of the raster after command (eg.county_roads_GDAL.tif)

Here are results, hope it helps: 
[image]

Must say, installing GDAL on WIN OS is real pain in the ...

Comment: Hi , is there any other way also to do this, without using gdal as u know 
as in windows os gdalwarp -dstalpha -srcnodata 256 -dstnodata 0 input.tif output.tif. not working

Comment: Yes, try raster clipping with QGIS

Comment: No, i want using python code only.

Comment: @sameer_nubia You ll need to create new question on that matter

Comment: As suggest, i have made new question,
can u plzz look into it
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64733639/rgb-tif-to-geotif-and-removing-the-background-color

Answer (score 1):

In the settings (in the layer page), try setting "output transparent color" to white

Comment: you meant _InputTransparentColor_ under subheader Coverage Parameters? if you do, I already tried that :(